# The tag "xxx" does not exist in XML namespace"yyy" / Reference could not be found

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, reference

I have a winform usercontrol than I want to add to wpf project.

I added the relevant references (WindowsFormsIntegration, SystemWindowsForms and my user control dll) and added this row in my XAML:

```
xmlns:MyControl="clr-namespace:xx.xx.xx;assembly=xx.xx"
```

And then this:

```
<WindowsFormsHost><MyControl:control></MyControl:control></WindowsFormsHost>
```

When I write "MyControl:" the "control" is automated show up that mean VS recognize the control and all references added ok... but when I compile the project this give me the error in the title.

**Edit**

Its very strange when I'm compile the all project i've got error "The type or namespace name "xx' could not be found..."
but I added all the refernces and the VS recognize the namespace so why the compiler don't found them? If this problem will be solved I beleive the other problem also will disappear.

Comment: Are your projects targetting the same .NET-Framework-Version?

Comment: I accidentally leaned on the keyboard and renamed my "Button3" to "Butto333333333333333n3" in the Assembly name in properties. Fixing that back to what it should be called fixed the issue. Check for silly typos, thats what itll be

Answer (score 42):

The solution is: Go to your project properties and change the `Target Framework` from `Client Profile` to the full version of the .Net you are using, see the image below. This problem happens if your DLL targets the full .NET Framework, and your WPF Application (main project) targets .Net Client Profile.

[image: Change Your Target Framework to the Full Version]

Comment: +1 it actually worked. the only question is why ? what is the story with the client profile.

Comment: @AdielYaacov, that happens if your DLL targets the full .NET Framework, and your WPF Application targets the Client Profile.

Comment: I had the same problem and the fix was very close to this. I was referencing a .NET v.4.5 library from a project that I'd accidentally created as .NET V.4. Upping the project version to .NET v4.5 fixed it.

Answer (score 21):

This happened to me when I included the assembly name in the namespace definition, but both controls were in the same assembly.  Just removing the assembly part of the namespace declaration solved it.

Answer (score 14):

Visual Studio will load the reference only for reflection so it will show correct intellisense correctly. But in order to compile, compiler will need all the dlls that your referenced dll is dependent on. So visual studio will show intellisense for mycontrol as it can find it in reference. But your myontrol may reference other dlls which you may not have added. You will have to add dependent references of mycontrol in your project too.

Answer (score 5):

It could also be that the target framework is different between your projects.  We host a class library dll with the WPF pages, and it was targeted to 'Any CPU', but the host application was targeted to 'x86'.  Once they matched, the problem went away.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same *"The type or namespace name 'xx' could not be found..."* issue.

It disappears when **I moved my Visual Studio files on a local drive**. They were stored on a shared network directory before. I dont know the root cause of this, but at least I can have my designer running now.

Comment: Have you try to make a "Clean" of the whole solution, or/and delete the bin directories ? (Of course, take care about external dependencies :))

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem before and replacing `<MyControl:control></MyControl:control>` with just `<MyControl:control/>` fixed it for me.

No idea why though. It seems like the first form is only for controls which can contain other controls.

Comment: Would you mind pasting in your actual XAML? (or is that pretty much it?)

Comment: @Tom I can paste it its in other computer anyway its pretty much it. Do you see my edit? I think my problem is the compiler can't found the refernce of my control

Comment: Indeed but the question is why. If you've added the project reference and the XML namespace then why can the compiler not find it? Especially when intellisense can.

I'm quite interested to find the answer to this myself having encountered this before. Would like to know for future reference.

Comment: Sometimes the solution for problems like this is to create a new project builds the dll again and start all from new I'll hope its will help. Thanks for you trying to help

Comment: Well if you do find a solution, make sure to report back here